# DFGLS tests in R

Tags: r, time-series, stata

Stata has a very good implementation of the DFGLS procedure (documentation available [here](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/tsdfgls.pdf)). I am trying to replicate that in R. I have the following code (mostly copied from `urca`'s `ur.ers` ). However, the code I have now is throwing an error (Error in yd.dlags[, c(1:i)] : subscript out of bounds). I don't understand why this is the case. Any help?

y in this case would be a time-series object (though the function treats it as a vector).

```
dfgls <- function(y){
  nobs <- length(y)
  M <- floor(12*((nobs +1)/100)^0.25)
  idx <- 2:M
  y <- na.omit(as.vector(y))
  lags <- numeric()
  critvals <- numeric()
  ahat <- 1 - 13.5/nobs
  ya <- c(y[1], y[2:nobs] - ahat * y[1:(nobs - 1)])
  za1 <- c(1, rep(1 - ahat, nobs - 1))
  trd <- 1:nobs
  za2 <- c(1, trd[2:nobs] - ahat * trd[1:(nobs - 1)])
  yd.reg <- summary(lm(ya ~ -1 + za1 + za2))
  yd <- y - coef(yd.reg)[1] - coef(yd.reg)[2] * trd
  yd.l <- yd[1:(nobs - 1)]
  yd.diff <- diff(yd)
  yd.dlags <- embed(diff(yd), M)[, -1]
  i <- M
    while (i >= 1){
    data.dfgls <- data.frame(cbind(yd.diff, yd.l, yd.dlags[, c(1:i)]))
    colnames(data.dfgls) <- c("yd.diff", "yd.lag", paste(rep(i, "y.diff.lag")))
    dfgls.form <- formula(paste("yd.diff ~ -1 + yd.lag", paste(rep(i, "y.diff.lag"))))
    dfgls.reg <- summary(lm(dfgls.form, data = data.dfgls))
    teststat <- coef(dfgls.reg)[1, 3]
    test.reg <- dfgls.reg
    critvals[i] <- teststat
    lags[i] <- i
    i <- i -1
  }
  dat <- data.frame(lags, critvals)
}
```

Comment: Do the existing R functions (adf.test in tseries and fUnitRoots) not replicate the Stata function?

Comment: No, they do not. They only run the DFGLS test once (for a fixed lag), and do not report the kinds of criteria for selecting which lag is "best." (e.g. Ng-Perron sequential t, etc)

Answer (score 2):

"Debug my code" is not really on-topic here. If you want to offer a sample and some debugging steps that identifies where it goes wrong,we can help.  There is a code review forum. Package 'fUnitRoots' has several uniroot test options including an augmented Dickey-Fuller. You can also find `adf.test` in pkg:tseries.